# How to use LESS in React 16.7 with webpack 4.29?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, less

I am just start to learn React, and I want to use less in React. I did some research about it , and they said I should write the config in `webpack.config.dev.js` but , after I run `npm run eject` I only got one file :`webpack.config.js` .

I think maybe that's because the update , the new version maybe combined webpack.config.dev.js and webpack.config.prod.js to `webpack.config.js .

and I checked the homepage of webpack , it says:

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  ...
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      issuer: /\.less$/,
      use: [{
        loader: 'js-to-less-loader'
      }]
    }]
  }
};
```

but I don't know where to insert these code. I did not find any code like that.so I want a simple example for how to support less in React.

Thanks.

Comment: global search 'rules'， it can be defined in other files in the same directory as `webpack.config.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the following steps after ejecting to use less in react

```
1. Go to webpack.config.js file and search for cssRegex change it from /\.css$/ to /\.(?:le|c)ss$/
2. install less and less loader using npm install -S less less-loader
3. search for getStyleLoaders method in webpack config file and add the following object to array of loaders specified over there
    {
     loader: require.resolve('less-loader'),
     options: {
      importLoaders: 1,
     },
    }
```

Then you will be good to go, feel free to ask for clarifications if any

Comment: thank you , I have tired your method . but it is not work . I want to post the code . but seems the comment area is not a good place to post code.

Comment: @Neko What is the issue you are facing. You can create a reproducable git repo and share the same so that i can try it out

Comment: it's so kind of you , I upload the code to github :https://github.com/jjzjx118/ReactTest.git , thanks for checking it.

Comment: @Neko Looks Like you have not included approprate css-loaders in that config use can you try replacing your whole webpack config with the one included in this file https://github.com/sumanthmadishetty/react-ejected/blob/master/config/webpack.config.js

Comment: @Neko I have tried replacing your webpack config with the file specified. It worked for me, Let me know If you face any issues

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using the create-react-app starter kit.
Well its good but if you want to add more features to your setup, Starter kits come with their own complications.

You can learn to setup react instead of letting the starter kit handling it for you.

Anyways you can try this,

You will need babel depedencies for handling transpilation:

```
npm install babel-core babel-loader babel-preset-env babel-preset-react --save-dev
```

Setup your react dependencies like so:

```
npm i react react-dom --save-dev
```

Once you are done with this setup, include your .bablerc file with the following code:

```
{
  "presets" : [
    "env",
    "react"
  ]
}
```

Setup dependencies to load your css/less files.
This will fetch all the loaders you require for css and less.

```
npm install less less-loader style-loader css-loader --save--dev
```

Now you will need an HTML plugin and a template *.html* file for webpack to serve your react.

```
npm i html-webpack-plugin html-loader --save-dev
```

The template file (save this as src/index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
</head>
<style>
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div class='content' id='app'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

You will now need a webpack devServer for serving the generated index.html

```
npm install webpack-dev-server --save-dev
```

Add the following to your package.json file

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "webpack --mode development",
  "build": "webpack --mode production"
}
```

By now you should be having a webpack.config.js file, which fairly looks like this.

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    const {
        mode
    } = argv;
    return {
        module: {
            entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'app.js'),
            watch: mode !== 'production',
            output: {
                path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
                filename: mode === 'production' ? 'bundle.min.js' : 'bundle.js'
            },
            rules: [{
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'less-loader']
            }
            ],
            plugins: [
                new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
                    title: 'App',
                    template: "./src/index.html",
                    filename: "./index.html"
                })
            ]
        },
        devServer: {
            contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
        }
    };
}
```

And a app.js file in your src folder like so,

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './styles/style.less'

ReactDOM.render( <div> Hello from react! </div>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Use `npm start` to run the dev version.

Hope this helps. Let me know if you face any issues.
I agree this is tedious work for the first time. But it does help in the long run to scale with features.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is a good way to understand how webpack works . I will try it